# Statement.execute(sql) vs executeUpdate(sql) and executeQuery(sql)

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have a question related to this method: `st.execute(sql);` where st obviously is a Statement object.
Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html#executing_queries) oracle java tutorial:

> execute: Returns true if the first object that the query returns is a
>   ResultSet object. Use this method if the query could return one or
>   more ResultSet objects. Retrieve the ResultSet objects returned from
>   the query by repeatedly calling Statement.getResutSet.

What is meant by "***one or more ResultSet objects***"? How is it possible to manage them once got an array of `ResultSet`? 
Whereas `st.executeQuery(sql)` and `st.executeUpdate(sql)` are very clear. It's not (at least to me) the aim of `st.execute(sql)` which can also return an int as if it was updated a table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What do they mean by "one or more ResultSet objects"?

The javadoc for the `execute` method says this:

> "*Executes the given SQL statement, which may return multiple results. In some (uncommon) situations, a single SQL statement may return multiple result sets and/or update counts. Normally you can ignore this unless you are (1) executing a stored procedure that you know may return multiple results or (2) you are dynamically executing an unknown SQL string.*"

That pretty much explains it.  Sometimes a query can deliver more than one `ResultSet`.

> if so how is it possible to manage them once got an array of ResultSet?

I'm not sure what you mean but:

- you can't get them as an array: you must get them one at a time, and
- you could put the ResultSets into an array ...

> It's not (at least to me) the aim of st.execute(sql) which can also return an int as if it was updated a table.

One of the supported use-cases of `execute` mentioned in the quoted javadoc is to execute an unknown SQL statement.  In this case, you don't know if it is a query, an update (of some kind) ... or something else that potentially delivers multiple result sets.  This use-case *requires* the method to be able to return multiple results in some cases.

---

Basically, `execute` is a generalization of `executeQuery()` and `executeUpdate()`.  If you don't need the generality, use the specialized versions instead.

Answer (score 33):

`boolean execute():`
Executes the SQL statement in this `PreparedStatement` object, which may be any kind of SQL statement.

`ResultSet executeQuery():`
Executes the SQL query in this `PreparedStatement` object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

`int executeUpdate():`
Executes the SQL statement in this `PreparedStatement` object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

The best place to find answers to questions like this is the Javadocs:
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I ran into "Prepared SQL statement is not a query" found this answer useful.

Answer (score 8):

**execute() :** The method used for all types of SQL statements, and that is, returns a boolean value of TRUE or FALSE. If the method return TRUE, return the ResultSet object and FALSE returns the int value.

**executeUpdate() :** This method is used for execution of DML statement(INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE) which is return int value, count of the affected rows.

**executeQuery() :** This method is used to retrieve data from database using SELECT query. This method returns the ResultSet object that returns the data according to the query.