# Spring Data JPA - The statement did not return a result set

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my application I have a model that relates to itself in a parent/child relationship. Posts can have parents that are also posts. I've written a query to delete a target post and its descendants. When I execute the query outside of Spring it works perfectly. However when running it in Spring, the query executes successfully but throws the following exception:

```
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - The statement did not return a result set.
ERROR [dispatcherServlet]:182 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
```

My query runs from an interface that extends JpaRepository

```
@Query(value = "WITH ParentTree AS (\n" +
            "  SELECT Parent.post_key,\n" +
            "    1 AS Level\n" +
            "  FROM community_post AS Parent\n" +
            "    WHERE Parent.post_key = ?1\n" +
            "    UNION ALL\n" +
            "      SELECT Child.post_key,\n" +
            "        pt.Level + 1\n" +
            "      FROM community_post AS Child\n" +
            "      INNER JOIN ParentTree AS pt\n" +
            "        ON Child.post_parent = pt.post_key\n" +
            "      WHERE Child.post_parent IS NOT NULL\n" +
            ")\n" +
            "DELETE FROM community_post\n" +
            "  WHERE post_key IN (\n" +
            "      SELECT post_key\n" +
            "      FROM ParentTree\n" +
            "  )", nativeQuery = true)
    void recursiveDelete(long targetKey);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you want to add the @Modifying annotation as well. See the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries). It's because SQL Delete does not return a resultset.

EDIT 1:

It comes down to execute (or executeQuery) vs executeUpdate if you're familiar with the JDBC API. Looks like Spring has the expectation that your method annotated with @Query will return a resultset and so it's disappointed when it doesn't. Related SO question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625656/statement-executesql-vs-executeupdatesql-and-executequerysql).

Comment: `@Modifying` along with `@Transactional` did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Add **@Modifying** annotation if it is missing with **@Query**.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error when using `@Modifying` though I use the Create query using the stored procedure.

I need to use `@Transactional` with `@Modifying` that solve my problem.

My code:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "exec [cmpl].[CreateComplaintHistory] :complaintNumber,:eventType, :eventCreator, " +
            ":deptFrom, :deptTo, :assignedUser ",  nativeQuery = true)

void createComplaintHistory(
        @Param("complaintNumber") String complaintNumber,
        @Param("eventType") String eventType,
        @Param("eventCreator") String eventCreator,
        @Param("deptFrom") String deptFrom,
        @Param("deptTo") String deptTo,
        @Param("assignedUser") String assignedUser
    );
```

Another solution for my stored procedure:

I use `@Procedure` annotation and remove `@Modifying` `@Transactional`

Code:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "cmpl.CreateComplaintHistory")
void createComplaintHistory(@Param("complaintNumber") String complaintNumber,
        @Param("eventType") String eventType,
        @Param("eventCreator") String eventCreator,
        @Param("deptFrom") String deptFrom,
        @Param("deptTo") String deptTo,
        @Param("assignedUser") String assignedUser
    );
```

Comment: Modifying along with Transactional: I don't know if it is the right approach or not.