# How to execute a SQL statement in Java with variables

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following mysql statement to delete records from a DB that is working.

```
SET @email = 'delete@mailinator.com';
SET @userID = (SELECT id FROM USER WHERE email = @email);
DELETE FROM user_role_group WHERE user_id = @userID;
DELETE FROM user_client_setup WHERE user_id = @userID;
DELETE FROM USER WHERE id = @userID;
```

I want to run this same query in Java with a jdbc mysql connection. I have tried the following

```
public void deleteCoreUser(String email) {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://db.com:3306/core","username","password");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SET @email = '"+email+"';\n" +
                    "SET @userID = (SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = @email);\n" +
                    "DELETE FROM user_role_group WHERE user_id = @userID;\n" +
                    "DELETE FROM user_client_setup WHERE user_id = @userID;\n" +
                    "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = @userID;");
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Deleting user "+email+" from the Core DB");
        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
    }
```

I am getting this error when running

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @userID = (SELECT id
>   FROM user WHERE email = @email); DELETE FROM user_role_' at line 2

Comment: Look for "prepared statement jdbc"

Comment: PreparedStatement will simplify the same query. It has performance benefit also as the query is compiled once and executed multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MySQL queries are running correctly in MySQL console, then there is no reason that same query will show syntax error when handling it with `jdbc`. You are making mistakes in implementing the queries with java and how java handles it.

```
public void deleteCoreUser(String email) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://db.com:3306/core","username","password");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SET @email = '" + email + "'";
        stmt.execute(sql);
        sql = "SET @userID = (SELECT id FROM USER WHERE email = @email)";
        stmt.execute(sql);
        sql = "DELETE FROM user_role_group WHERE user_id = @userID";
        stmt.execute(sql);
        sql = "DELETE FROM user_client_setup WHERE user_id = @userID";
        stmt.execute(sql);
        sql = "DELETE FROM USER WHERE id = @userID";
        stmt.execute(sql);
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Deleting user " + email + " from the Core DB");
    } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
}
```

`stmt.executeQuery` is used when you try to get resultset from the queries. But in this case you are not asking for resultset. That's why no `Resultset` is necessary and only `stmt.execute` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Use execute() instead of executeQuery() since it returns multiple ResultSet. See answer ([Statement.execute(sql) vs executeUpdate(sql) and executeQuery(sql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625656/statement-executesql-vs-executeupdatesql-and-executequerysql)) and add *?allowMultiQueries=true* to the database url 
     `"jdbc:mysql://db.com:3306/core?allowMultiQueries=true"`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is due to the allowMultiQueries flag in MariaDB. This defaults to `false`, meaning each query is essentially run in a vacuum and your `SET @userID = (SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = @email);` query doesn't know what `@email` is. To resolve this with you current code, set the database `allowMultiQueries=true`.